# An unfair coin tossed twice.

Tags: probability

Prove that for an unfair coin
$$P(HH)+P(TT) > P(HT)+P(TH).$$

That is, if a coin has "probability of heads" unequal to "probability of tails" ($P(H) \ne \frac{1}{2}$), and the coin is tossed twice, the probability of a repeat ("heads, heads" or "tails, tails") on the second toss is more likely than either "heads followed by tails" or "tails followed by heads."

Comment: That's three problems. Better to post one, then think about the answers you get, see whether they help you answer the others on your own; if not, post one more, etc.

Comment: Problem 2 is easily answered with Bayes' rule.

Comment: Notation confusion.  What do you mean by (HH,TT) as opposed to (HT,TH)?

Comment: What's the idea with problem 3?  They want to arrange some experiment with three outcomes, each with probability $1/3$?

Comment: Terrible title.  Rewrite it referring to the *content* of the problem.

Comment: Pls split these into separate questions and post along with your attempt.

Comment: Thank you. I will split into separate questions. I am new to this site. Trying to understand the way it works.

Comment: Wow!  Where did questions two and three go?  I agree with the comments that the typical style of posting is one-at-a-time, but we could have simply handled them all here.

Comment: Is it ok to post the remaining questions here also? I'm new to this site and trying to understand the rules

Comment: @Senator, my advice is don't worry too much about it.  You've gotten plenty of feedback already about style (maybe more forthcoming?).   Just learn the "culture" and post using $\TeX\ / \text{MathJax}$ and people will be friendly ...

Comment: @ mjw, thank you!

Comment: @mjw what if you posted an answer to (1), and I posted an answer to (2), and someone else posted an answer to (3). How would OP decide which answer to accept? That's a reason to have one question per post, not three.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I see your point.  Okay, makes sense that every question has its own posting.  My thinking was, once a few problems are already posted, do we really need to delete all-but-one, and post them again somewhere else.  I guess it depends on the "problems".  But I am with you, going forward let's all agree to post one problem at a time, please.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, how do you like the new title?

Comment: @ mjw, @ GerryMyerson..thanks guys

Comment: Notifying two users in one comment doesn't work, Senator.

Comment: oh ok. thank you Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Two:

P(Two Headed | Head) = P(Head | Two Headed) P( Two Headed) / P(Head).

$$P(\text{Two Headed}|\text{Head}) = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{2}{5}}{ \frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{5}} = \frac{4}{5}. $$

Comment: Thank you! I got the same answer!

Answer (score 0):

Problem one:  Let $p=P(H), q=P(T)=1-p, \quad \text{with } p\neq q.$

$$P(HH)+P(TT) = p^2+q^2$$

$$P(HT)+P(TH) = 2pq.$$

$$P(HH)+P(TT)-[P(HT)+P(TH)]=(p-q)^2>0.$$

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense